# Linux Top command Residend memory always growing

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to check if my firmware for an embedded intercom on a embedded linux board has some memory leakage.
Using the top command, I was surprised because the resident memory is always growing especially at the beginning when I start the process. After a while the momory consumption becomes more stable.

So I made an experiment by adding some code to allocate and free 2K memory block. What I found was that when I allocate the memory the first time the RES memory showed by the top command increases, but when I free it, the RES does not decreases.
In any case if I call malloc a second (or third,...) time to get a new 2K memory block, the RES does not increase anymore.
Even if I wait some time the RES memory never decreases.

It looks like top returns the maximum amount of memory used an not the memory used at a certain time.

Comment: In a hosted environment (that is, running on top of an operating system such as Linux), it is normal that once the OS assigns memory to a process, the process keeps it until it terminates.  This is a lower-level consideration then `malloc()` and `free()`, which will work within the memory already assigned to the process until and unless they run out and need to acquire more from the OS.

Comment: If you want to check for memory leakage then use a tool designed specifically for that, such as Valgrind.